# Why is this show hide javascript causing problems within a cms

Tags: javascript, html

The code is supposed to show or hide inputs (and other elements) on a form inside of a CMS.  However some of the attachments act as if they were deleted and do not get processed or sent on.  Without me posting several pages of code and explaining the CMS specific code what can you tell me about this block of code that might cause problems?

This is the relevant piece of code i have narrowed my problem down to.

```
function setShowHide(num, min)
{
    var terminate = false;

    if (num < 0) // minus
    {
        for(x = 4; x > 0; x--) 
        {
            if(terminate != true)
            {
                if(showHideArray[x] == 1 && AttArray[x] == 0)
                {
                    hide(x + 1);
                    showHideArray[x] = 0;
                    terminate = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (num > 0) // plus
    {
        for(x = 0; x < 5; x++) 
        {
            if(terminate != true)
            {
                if(showHideArray[x] == 0)
                {
                    Show(x + 1);
                    showHideArray[x] = 1;
                    terminate = true;
                }
            }    
        }
    }
}

function hide(i) {

    changeObjectVisibility("Attachmenttd" + i, "none");
    changeObjectVisibility("Attachment" + i + "File", "none");
    changeObjectVisibility("Attachment" + i + "Description", "none");
    changeObjectVisibility("Attachment" + i + "If", "none");
}           

function Show(j) {                   
    changeObjectVisibility("Attachmenttd" + j, "inline");
    changeObjectVisibility("Attachment" + j + "File", "inline");
    changeObjectVisibility("Attachment" + j + "Description", "inline");
    changeObjectVisibility("Attachment" + j + "If", "inline");

}

function changeObjectVisibility(objectId, newVisibility) {
    // first get the object's stylesheet
    var styleObject = getStyleObject(objectId);
    // then if we find a stylesheet, set its visibility
    // as requested
    //
    if (styleObject) {
        styleObject.display = newVisibility;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function getStyleObject(objectId) {
    // checkW3C DOM, then MSIE 4, then NN 4.
    //
    if (document.getElementById(objectId)) {
        return document.getElementById(objectId).style;
    }
    else if (document.all && document.all(objectId)) {
        return document.all(objectId).style;
    }
    else if (document.layers && document.layers[objectId]) {
        return document.layers[objectId];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this your exact code? I see a bunch of things like `if (num &gt; 0)` where `>` has been encoded as the entity `&gt;` instead of `if (num > 0)`. If your CMS is outputting the JavaScript, that's probably your problem

Comment: On the other hand, if those entities are the result of you copy/pasting this code from some kind of HTML code display, please edit it above to be your correct JavaScript.

Comment: I formatted the code and replaced encoded HTML with the proper symbols. If this was an incorrect edit **please roll it back**. Next time, please indent your code so that people can read it and assist you more quickly

Comment: Please keep in mind the line in my post --- Without me posting several pages of code and explaining the CMS specific code --- The entities are required or the cms throws a system xml exception.  I will take the time to indent the code in the future.  No the cms does not indent any of the code in fact it regularly screws it up everytime i save it.

Comment: Michael can you please explain more about the cms outputting the javascript and how it affects my script? @Michael

Comment: @user1015711 When you originally posted, before others edited, your code wasn't valid JavaScript, but was HTML-encoded for display. So I wondered if your CMS had output the JavaScript as though it was to be displayed (and encoded it accordingly per my earlier comments) instead of outputting it to be executed.  I don't know the circumstances that would cause that situation, but your original code post looked like it.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of issues with your code (which may or may not explain the symptoms you are complaining about):

Your two for loops are not operating on the same array elements:

```
for(x = 4; x > 0; x--)

for(x = 0; x < 5; x++)
```

Within both loops you have `showHideArray[x]`, but the first loop is counting down to process elements 4,3,2,1 (stop), while the second is counting up to process elements 0,1,2,3,4 (stop). That is, only the second loop processes element 0. The first for loop should probably be:

```
for(x = 4; x >= 0; x--)          //    >= 0 rather than > 0
```

Note also that you didn't declare `x` so it will be a global - which might have a negative effect on other parts of your code if they also have an undeclared `x`.

I don't think it causes any problems, but you do not need the `terminate` variable and `if(!terminate)` stuff - that's what the [`break` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) is for.

You don't ever use the `min` parameter.

Regarding your `getStyleObject()` function, do you really need to support browsers that don't have `getElementById()`? Or is this an attempt to allow for the supplied parameter possibly being an id or possibly being a name?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I will use your comments to improve my coding skills in the future.  Currently the script works ok up until the part where the attachments fail to show up or be recognized within the cms.  Is there any other reasons that would cause the cms to not show the attachemnts?  I will update later today with some improvements that have been mentioned.

Comment: Regarding the getStyleObject() I got that code and supporting functions from a community supported by the cms.  Are you telling thjis function is for cross browser support and can be replaced with getElementById() and still work in most browsers?